# Kinetic error: opencv2/core/core.hpp No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, catkin, opencv2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ROS kinetic on ubuntu 16.04

after a system update with Software-Updater i get an error while catkin_make-ing.
worked like a charm before.

```
In file included from /home/alexander/git/human_detector/catkin_ws/src/human_detector/src/background.cpp:3:0: /opt/ros/kinetic/include/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h:43:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (No such file or directory) compilation terminated.
```

get this for every file i included cv_bridge....

edit: i dont know if its important but i found the update history from that point in time when things stopped working

```
Start-Date: 2017-03-23  14:29:03
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.153'
Install: libappstream4:amd64 (0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2, automatic), libstemmer0d:amd64 (0+svn585-1, automatic)
Upgrade: ros-kinetic-interactive-markers:amd64 (1.11.3-0xenial-20170227-161835-0800, 1.11.3-0xenial-20170308-212223-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-py:amd64 (0.3.2-0xenial-20170227-152338-0800, 0.3.2-0xenial-20170308-221141-0800), ros-kinetic-opencv3:amd64 (3.2.0-2xenial-20170226-170515-0800, 3.2.0-4xenial-20170315-013656-0700), ros-kinetic-eigen-stl-containers:amd64 (0.1.6-0xenial-20170217-220112-0800, 0.1.8-0xenial-20170310-121851-0800), ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs:amd64 (0.5.15-0xenial-20170227-131925-0800, 0.5.15-0xenial-20170308-183301-0800), ros-kinetic-geometric-shapes:amd64 (0.5.2-0xenial-20170227-142025-0800, 0.5.2-0xenial-20170310-122242-0800), ros-kinetic-rospy:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-142222-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-183940-0800), ros-kinetic-desktop:amd64 (1.3.0-0xenial-20170302-223605-0800, 1.3.0-0xenial-20170316-165147-0700), ros-kinetic-roslaunch:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-143335-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-192730-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-tf-tree:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-220927-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221819-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-moveit:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-221012-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221859-0800), ros-kinetic-visualization-marker-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-143139-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170308-193413-0800), ros-kinetic-ros-base:amd64 (1.3.0-0xenial-20170227-160140-0800, 1.3.0-0xenial-20170308-211001-0800), ros-kinetic-roslisp:amd64 (1.9.20-0xenial-20170227-132204-0800, 1.9.20-0xenial-20170308-184833-0800), ros-kinetic-ros-comm:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-155832-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-210535-0800), ros-kinetic-nodelet-topic-tools:amd64 (1.9.9-0xenial-20170227-155019-0800, 1.9.9-0xenial-20170308-195955-0800), ros-kinetic-ros-core:amd64 (1.3.0-0xenial-20170227-155952-0800, 1.3.0-0xenial-20170308-210730-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-console:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215342-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222005-0800), ros-kinetic-tf2-ros:amd64 (0.5.15-0xenial-20170227-160309-0800, 0.5.15-0xenial-20170308-210920-0800), ros-kinetic-rospy-tutorials:amd64 (0.7.1-0xenial-20170227-144304-0800, 0.7.1-0xenial-20170308-193605-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-pose-view:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-221102-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221802-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-163638-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-214054-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-logger-level:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214359-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221845-0800), ros-kinetic-topic-tools:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-144325-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-193558-0800), ros-kinetic-roslib:amd64 (1.13.5-0xenial-20170227-130826-0800, 1.13.5-0xenial-20170308-181854-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostic-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-131424-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-182759-0800), ros-kinetic-rosgraph-msgs:amd64 (1.11.2-0xenial-20170227-131933-0800, 1.11.2-0xenial-20170308-183114-0800), ros-kinetic-robot-model:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-163412-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170310-123927-0800), ros-kinetic-roslz4:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-143629-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-182349-0800), libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), appstream:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu2, 0.10.6-1~ubuntu16.04.2), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-rosmsg:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-152432-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194441-0800), ros-kinetic-eigen-conversions:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-140332-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-191208-0800), ros-kinetic-resource-retriever:amd64 (1.12.2-0xenial-20170227-141639-0800, 1.12.2-0xenial-20170308-184725-0800), ros-kinetic-rosservice:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-152738-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194759-0800), libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.5), ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-143026-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-192419-0800), ros-kinetic-ros:amd64 (1.13.5-0xenial-20170227-140935-0800, 1.13.5-0xenial-20170308-190952-0800), ros-kinetic-kdl-parser:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-144926-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194201-0800), ros-kinetic-control-msgs:amd64 (1.4.0-0xenial-20170227-133229-0800, 1.4.0-0xenial-20170308-183651-0800), ros-kinetic-rviz-plugin-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-203301-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170309-010413-0800), ros-kinetic-bond:amd64 (1.7.18-0xenial-20170227-131410-0800, 1.7.18-0xenial-20170308-182743-0800), ros-kinetic-rosout:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-142920-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-192416-0800), ros-kinetic-bondcpp:amd64 (1.7.18-0xenial-20170227-142154-0800, 1.7.18-0xenial-20170308-191846-0800), ros-kinetic-tf2:amd64 (0.5.15-0xenial-20170227-141723-0800, 0.5.15-0xenial-20170308-192216-0800), ros-kinetic-trajectory-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-132341-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-183509-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214959-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-210625-0800), ros-kinetic-geometry:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-163348-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-214546-0800), ros-kinetic-turtle-actionlib:amd64 (0.1.10-0xenial-20170227-160128-0800, 0.1.10-0xenial-20170308-210711-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-rviz:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170227-170212-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221154-0800), ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials:amd64 (0.7.1-0xenial-20170227-151242-0800, 0.7.1-0xenial-20170308-193952-0800), ros-kinetic-pr2-description:amd64 (1.12.0-0xenial-20170227-203136-0800, 1.12.0-0xenial-20170309-003548-0800), ros-kinetic-tf-conversions:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-161512-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-213602-0800), ros-kinetic-viz:amd64 (1.3.0-0xenial-20170302-222252-0800, 1.3.0-0xenial-20170315-050401-0700), ros-kinetic-nav-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-131914-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-183252-0800), ros-kinetic-stereo-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-132512-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-184013-0800), ros-kinetic-pluginlib-tutorials:amd64 (0.1.10-0xenial-20170227-144849-0800, 0.1.10-0xenial-20170308-193419-0800), ros-kinetic-collada-parser:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-145024-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194222-0800), ros-kinetic-common-tutorials:amd64 (0.1.10-0xenial-20170227-161423-0800, 0.1.10-0xenial-20170308-214804-0800), ros-kinetic-visualization-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-132221-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-183526-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-service-caller:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215600-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-223053-0800), libc6:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-bond-core:amd64 (1.7.18-0xenial-20170227-143123-0800, 1.7.18-0xenial-20170308-192230-0800), ros-kinetic-nodelet:amd64 (1.9.9-0xenial-20170227-142544-0800, 1.9.9-0xenial-20170308-192127-0800), ros-kinetic-rosbuild:amd64 (1.13.5-0xenial-20170227-130940-0800, 1.13.5-0xenial-20170308-182204-0800), ros-kinetic-collada-urdf:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-161415-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170310-123104-0800), locales:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-qt-dotgraph:amd64 (0.3.4-0xenial-20170227-144131-0800, 0.3.4-0xenial-20170308-200807-0800), ros-kinetic-roswtf:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-155539-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-210221-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-topic:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214823-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221728-0800), ros-kinetic-librviz-tutorial:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-170217-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170308-220506-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-bag:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214220-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221724-0800), ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial:amd64 (0.2.4-0xenial-20170227-203605-0800, 0.2.4-0xenial-20170309-004251-0800), ros-kinetic-map-msgs:amd64 (1.13.0-0xenial-20170227-132427-0800, 1.13.0-0xenial-20170308-183714-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-220038-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170315-042717-0700), ros-kinetic-smach-ros:amd64 (2.0.0-2xenial-20170227-160322-0800, 2.0.0-2xenial-20170308-210823-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostic-analysis:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-152428-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-194629-0800), ros-kinetic-rosbag-storage:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-151648-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-191526-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-dep:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214625-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222101-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-steering:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170227-152857-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221740-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-reconfigure:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215527-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222128-0800), ros-kinetic-turtlesim:amd64 (0.7.1-0xenial-20170227-142249-0800, 0.7.1-0xenial-20170308-184307-0800), ros-kinetic-pluginlib:amd64 (1.10.4-0xenial-20170227-141336-0800, 1.10.4-0xenial-20170308-184727-0800), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.5), ros-kinetic-rqt-gui:amd64 (0.3.2-0xenial-20170227-151914-0800, 0.3.2-0xenial-20170308-220648-0800), ros-kinetic-genpy:amd64 (0.6.4-0xenial-20170227-125221-0800, 0.6.5-0xenial-20170308-181016-0800), ros-kinetic-gencpp:amd64 (0.5.4-0xenial-20170217-220520-0800, 0.5.5-0xenial-20170308-180846-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostics:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-164039-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-215424-0800), ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64 (0.3.2-0xenial-20170227-140247-0800, 0.3.2-0xenial-20170308-185848-0800), libc-bin:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-rviz-python-tutorial:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-203325-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170309-010454-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostic-aggregator:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-144422-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-193714-0800), ros-kinetic-qt-gui-cpp:amd64 (0.3.4-0xenial-20170227-144634-0800, 0.3.4-0xenial-20170308-201126-0800), ros-kinetic-nodelet-tutorial-math:amd64 (0.1.10-0xenial-20170227-143008-0800, 0.1.10-0xenial-20170308-192533-0800), ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher:amd64 (1.13.4-0xenial-20170227-163055-0800, 1.13.4-0xenial-20170308-213249-0800), ros-kinetic-message-filters:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-144623-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-193633-0800), ros-kinetic-mk:amd64 (1.13.5-0xenial-20170227-140241-0800, 1.13.5-0xenial-20170308-185836-0800), ros-kinetic-geometry-tutorials:amd64 (0.2.2-0xenial-20170227-201846-0800, 0.2.2-0xenial-20170309-004442-0800), ros-kinetic-tf:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-160826-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-211336-0800), ros-kinetic-message-runtime:amd64 (0.4.12-0xenial-20170227-125728-0800, 0.4.12-0xenial-20170308-181648-0800), ros-kinetic-rosunit:amd64 (1.13.5-0xenial-20170227-140141-0800, 1.13.5-0xenial-20170308-182205-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-monitor:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-220922-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221854-0800), ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials:amd64 (0.1.10-0xenial-20170227-160053-0800, 0.1.10-0xenial-20170308-210743-0800), ros-kinetic-sensor-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-132053-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-183152-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-plot:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215403-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221732-0800), ros-kinetic-executive-smach:amd64 (2.0.0-2xenial-20170227-160504-0800, 2.0.0-2xenial-20170308-211014-0800), ros-kinetic-rosnode:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-155211-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-205752-0800), ros-kinetic-interactive-marker-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-163213-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170308-213733-0800), ros-kinetic-xacro:amd64 (1.11.2-0xenial-20170227-202651-0800, 1.11.2-0xenial-20170308-205557-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-msg:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215655-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222109-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-nav-view:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-221108-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221855-0800), ros-kinetic-turtle-tf2:amd64 (0.2.2-0xenial-20170227-160838-0800, 0.2.2-0xenial-20170308-211349-0800), ros-kinetic-robot:amd64 (1.3.0-0xenial-20170227-203125-0800, 1.3.0-0xenial-20170316-162847-0700), ros-kinetic-rqt-shell:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214957-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222127-0800), ros-kinetic-rostest:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-143945-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-193235-0800), ros-kinetic-std-msgs:amd64 (0.5.11-0xenial-20170227-131008-0800, 0.5.11-0xenial-20170308-182154-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-cpp:amd64 (0.3.2-0xenial-20170227-150837-0800, 0.3.2-0xenial-20170308-201916-0800), ros-kinetic-geometry-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-131438-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-182846-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214513-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170315-031747-0700), ros-kinetic-qt-gui:amd64 (0.3.4-0xenial-20170227-144119-0800, 0.3.4-0xenial-20170308-200814-0800), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.5), ros-kinetic-rosconsole:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-140945-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-182447-0800), ros-kinetic-rosconsole-bridge:amd64 (0.4.4-0xenial-20170227-144251-0800, 0.4.4-0xenial-20170308-191658-0800), ros-kinetic-rviz:amd64 (1.12.4-0xenial-20170227-162335-0800, 1.12.4-0xenial-20170308-212658-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-runtime-monitor:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170227-152853-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-221732-0800), ros-kinetic-nodelet-core:amd64 (1.9.9-0xenial-20170227-155431-0800, 1.9.9-0xenial-20170308-201828-0800), ros-kinetic-cv-bridge:amd64 (1.12.4-0xenial-20170227-144540-0800, 1.12.4-0xenial-20170315-022155-0700), ros-kinetic-rospack:amd64 (2.3.2-0xenial-20170227-125456-0800, 2.3.3-0xenial-20170308-181000-0800), ros-kinetic-roscpp-tutorials:amd64 (0.7.1-0xenial-20170227-142305-0800, 0.7.1-0xenial-20170308-184203-0800), ros-kinetic-smach-msgs:amd64 (2.0.0-2xenial-20170227-132245-0800, 2.0.0-2xenial-20170308-184416-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-srv:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215828-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222551-0800), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-urdf:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-144630-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-193748-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-top:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214750-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221921-0800), ros-kinetic-shape-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-132058-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-183503-0800), multiarch-support:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu6, 2.23-0ubuntu7), ros-kinetic-rqt-publisher:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215515-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221658-0800), ros-kinetic-filters:amd64 (1.7.4-1xenial-20170227-144350-0800, 1.7.5-0xenial-20170316-161632-0700), ros-kinetic-bondpy:amd64 (1.7.18-0xenial-20170227-142734-0800, 1.7.18-0xenial-20170308-191818-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-bag-plugins:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215443-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221929-0800), ros-kinetic-message-generation:amd64 (0.4.0-0xenial-20170227-125711-0800, 0.4.0-0xenial-20170308-181930-0800), ros-kinetic-self-test:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-144914-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-194158-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-dashboard:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-221346-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170308-222215-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-web:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214856-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222020-0800), ros-kinetic-image-transport:amd64 (1.11.12-0xenial-20170227-145007-0800, 1.11.12-0xenial-20170308-193939-0800), ros-kinetic-common-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-141659-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-191814-0800), ros-kinetic-dynamic-reconfigure:amd64 (1.5.46-0xenial-20170227-152924-0800, 1.5.46-0xenial-20170308-195045-0800), ros-kinetic-actionlib-msgs:amd64 (1.12.5-0xenial-20170227-131404-0800, 1.12.5-0xenial-20170308-182735-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-launch:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215518-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222146-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-plugins:amd64 (0.5.6-0xenial-20170302-222158-0800, 0.5.6-0xenial-20170309-014549-0800), ros-kinetic-visualization-tutorials:amd64 (0.10.1-0xenial-20170227-203916-0800, 0.10.1-0xenial-20170309-013808-0800), ros-kinetic-rostopic:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-152427-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194406-0800), ros-kinetic-kdl-conversions:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-141855-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-192335-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-py-console:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214937-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221851-0800), ros-kinetic-rosbag:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-152113-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-194018-0800), ros-kinetic-qt-gui-py-common:amd64 (0.3.4-0xenial-20170227-144114-0800, 0.3.4-0xenial-20170308-200834-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-graph:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-214543-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-221654-0800), ros-kinetic-diagnostic-updater:amd64 (1.8.10-0xenial-20170227-144402-0800, 1.8.10-0xenial-20170308-193704-0800), ros-kinetic-tf2-kdl:amd64 (0.5.15-0xenial-20170227-160816-0800, 0.5.15-0xenial-20170308-211829-0800), ros-kinetic-roscpp:amd64 (1.12.7-0xenial-20170227-141340-0800, 1.12.7-0xenial-20170308-183157-0800), ros-kinetic-actionlib:amd64 (1.11.8-0xenial-20170227-155556-0800, 1.11.8-0xenial-20170308-210216-0800), ros-kinetic-std-srvs:amd64 (1.11.2-0xenial-20170227-131132-0800, 1.11.2-0xenial-20170308-182013-0800), ros-kinetic-turtle-tf:amd64 (0.2.2-0xenial-20170227-162241-0800, 0.2.2-0xenial-20170308-212918-0800), ros-kinetic-laser-geometry:amd64 (1.6.4-0xenial-20170227-161515-0800, 1.6.4-0xenial-20170308-212122-0800), ros-kinetic-rqt-action:amd64 (0.4.7-0xenial-20170302-215758-0800, 0.4.7-0xenial-20170308-222551-0800), ros-kinetic-tf2-py:amd64 (0.5.15-0xenial-20170227-145116-0800, 0.5.15-0xenial-20170308-193928-0800)
End-Date: 2017-03-23  14:30:15
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257960/kinetic-error:-opencv2/core/core.hpp-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Stoerakustik](https://answers.ros.org/users/28555/stoerakustik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-03-27**:
Did you try this?

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Comment by [Stoerakustik](https://answers.ros.org/users/28555/stoerakustik/) on 2017-03-27**:
yes i did, everything is up to date

this is a more or less brand new setup on my laptop - i installed everything last week (ubuntu ros and some things like dropbox and gitkraken) - cloned my repo and it worked, did the software update at some time and it stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the update history you have ros-kinetic-opencv3
I guess that now your ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} points to opencv3 instead of opencv2

Add this line in your CMakeList.txt, in order to see if this gets the value that you want

```
message( STATUS "OpenCV Include Dir: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

You can  define the version of OpenCV that you prefer in the CMakeLists.txt.

Example:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2.4.8 EXACT REQUIRED)
```

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stoerakustik](https://answers.ros.org/users/28555/stoerakustik/) on 2017-03-27**:
i added message( STATUS "OpenCV Include Dir: " ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ) and suddenly it works - shouldnt this only give me a feedback?

anyway it IS running by now - thank you good sir!

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-03-27**:
the message should not fix it. It only prints a message in your console. If I were you I would clean my build and devel folders and try to link the correct libraries in my CMakeList

PS I am not using kinetic and I am a woman. Sorry not a sir...

Auf wiederhören!

**Comment by [Stoerakustik](https://answers.ros.org/users/28555/stoerakustik/) on 2017-03-27**:
I removed the message from my cmakelists again, cleared my build and devel  and compiled again  - still works.

" and try to link the correct libraries in my CMakeList" im going to do that anyway.

much thanks and auf wiederhören ;)